# Handling Mapbox GeoJson lines across World Copies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I have a mapbox map that I am rendering points on and drawing lines between the points to create routes. The setup is working fine and the animations work as intended.

However when I have a line that crosses into a new world copy the curved line is drawn but another line is also drawn across the entire map.

[image: map]

Does anyone know a way of handling the drawing of the lines so they don't cross in to a new world render? Or have any idea on the best way to handle the drawing of the lines?

As a reference I am using the mapbox example found here:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-point-along-route/

```js
showRoute = route => {
  const steps = 500;

  const getRouteChunks = (array, size) => {
   const chunkedArr = [];

   array.forEach((arr, i) => {
    chunkedArr.push(array.slice(i, i + size));
   });

   return chunkedArr;
  };

  const routeChunks = getRouteChunks(route.destinations, 2);

  this.setState(prevState => {
   // Let's remove any existing route lines
   const mapLayers = prevState.map.style._layers;

   const midLayersOnlyToRemove = this.getMapboxLayersToRemove(mapLayers, '-midpoint');
   midLayersOnlyToRemove.forEach(activeLayer => {
    prevState.map.removeLayer(activeLayer.id);
   });

   const layersAndSourcesToRemove = this.getMapboxLayersToRemove(mapLayers, 'Route');
   layersAndSourcesToRemove.forEach(activeLayer => {
    prevState.map.removeLayer(activeLayer.id);
    prevState.map.removeSource(activeLayer.id);
   });

   const layersOnlyToRemove = this.getMapboxLayersToRemove(mapLayers, 'symbolPoint');
   layersOnlyToRemove.forEach(activeLayer => {
    prevState.map.removeLayer(activeLayer.id);
   });

   // Get a copy of all the geojson in state and then find the destinations we will need
   const { allGeoJson } = prevState;
   const destinationIds = route.destinations.map(dest => dest.id);
   const activeRouteDestinationsGeoJson = allGeoJson.features.filter(feature =>
    destinationIds.some(dId => dId === feature.properties.id)
   );

   // Setup the updated geojson object with the relvant destinations
   const activeRouteGeoJson = {
    features: activeRouteDestinationsGeoJson,
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
   };

   // Get the current markers that have been rendered in ReactDOM and remove them if they aren't needed
   const currentDomMarkers = document.querySelectorAll(`.current-mapoint-marker`);
   currentDomMarkers.forEach(marker => {
    const routeIds = marker.getAttribute('route-ids').split(',');
    const compareCatArrays = routeIds.some(c => c === route.id);
    if (!compareCatArrays) {
     marker.remove();
    }
   });

   // If the user clicks on a route that is already active, unset it and show all points again
   if (prevState.activeRouteId === route.id) {
    this.renderMarkers(allGeoJson);
    getMapboxJs().then(({ default: mapboxgl }) => {
     const bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();
     allGeoJson.features.forEach(feature => {
      bounds.extend(feature.geometry.coordinates);
     });
     prevState.map.fitBounds(bounds, {
      padding: { top: 200, bottom: 200, left: 200, right: 200 },
      easing(t) {
       return t * (2 - t);
      },
     });
    });

    return { geojson: allGeoJson, activeRouteId: null, activeRoute: null };
   }

   routeChunks.forEach((chunk, i) => {
    let counter = 0;
    const icon = route.routeSteps[i];
    const getIcon = icon => {
     switch (icon) {
      case 'Flight': {
       return 'airport-15';
      }
      case 'Train': {
       return 'rail-15';
      }
      default:
       return 'airport-15';
     }
    };

    const pointExists = prevState.map.getSource(`symbolPoint-${chunk[0].id}`);
    const lineExists = prevState.map.getSource(`Route-line-${i}`);

    const chunkPoint = {
     type: 'FeatureCollection',
     features: [
      {
       type: 'Feature',
       properties: {},
       geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: chunk[0].coordinates,
       },
      },
     ],
    };

    if (!pointExists) {
     prevState.map.addSource(`symbolPoint-${chunk[0].id}`, {
      type: 'geojson',
      data: chunkPoint,
     });
    }
    const chunkLength = chunk.length;
    if (chunkLength === 2) {
     const chunkRoute = {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: [
       {
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
         type: 'LineString',
         coordinates: [chunk[0].coordinates, chunk[1].coordinates],
        },
       },
      ],
     };

     const chunkLine = lineString([...chunkRoute.features[0].geometry.coordinates]);
     const chunkLineDistance = length(chunkLine, { units: 'miles' });

     const chunkArc = [];
     // Draw an arc between the `origin` & `destination` of the two points
     for (let j = 0; j < chunkLineDistance; j += chunkLineDistance / steps) {
      const segment = along(chunkRoute.features[0], j, { units: 'miles' });
      chunkArc.push(segment.geometry.coordinates);
     }

     chunkRoute.features[0].geometry.coordinates = chunkArc;

     if (!lineExists) {
      prevState.map.addSource(`Route-line-${i}`, {
       type: 'geojson',
       data: chunkRoute,
      });
     }

     prevState.map.addLayer({
      id: `Route-line-${i}`,
      source: `Route-line-${i}`,
      type: 'line',
      paint: {
       'line-width': 2,
       'line-color': '#007cbf',
      },
     });

     prevState.map.addLayer({
      id: `symbolPoint-${chunk[0].id}`,
      source: `symbolPoint-${chunk[0].id}`,
      type: 'symbol',
      layout: {
       'icon-image': getIcon(icon),
       'icon-rotate': ['get', 'bearing'],
       'icon-rotation-alignment': 'map',
       'icon-allow-overlap': true,
       'icon-ignore-placement': true,
      },
     });

     const animate = () => {
      // Update point geometry to a new position based on counter denoting
      // the index to access the arc.
      const nextPoint = chunkRoute.features[0].geometry.coordinates[counter + 1];
      if (chunkRoute.features[0].geometry.coordinates[counter] !== undefined) {
       chunkPoint.features[0].geometry.coordinates = chunkRoute.features[0].geometry.coordinates[counter];

       // Calculate the bearing to ensure the icon is rotated to match the route arc
       // The bearing is calculate between the current point and the next point, except
       // at the end of the arc use the previous point and the current point
       if (nextPoint) {
        chunkPoint.features[0].properties.bearing = bearing(
         point(chunkRoute.features[0].geometry.coordinates[counter >= steps ? counter - 1 : counter]),
         point(chunkRoute.features[0].geometry.coordinates[counter >= steps ? counter : counter + 1])
        );
       }

       // Update the source with this new data.
       prevState.map.getSource(`symbolPoint-${chunk[0].id}`).setData(chunkPoint);

       // Request the next frame of animation so long the end has not been reached.
       if (counter < steps) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
       }
       counter += 1;
      }
     };

     animate(counter);
    }
   });

   getMapboxJs().then(({ default: mapboxgl }) => {
    const bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds();

    route.destinations.forEach(destination => {
     bounds.extend(destination.coordinates);
    });

    prevState.map.fitBounds(bounds, {
     padding: { top: 200, bottom: 200, left: 200, right: 200 },
     easing(t) {
      return t * (2 - t);
     },
    });
   });

   // Re-render the markers and then update state
   this.renderMarkers(activeRouteGeoJson);
   return { geojson: activeRouteGeoJson, activeRouteId: route.id, activeRoute: route };
  });
 };
```

Comment: Please add your code, so we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: @TsahiAsher have added a code snippet now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a fix for this by using Turf.js and using the great-circle package it has. All you have to do is get the coordinates of the start and end point of the line you're drawing and pass them through to a greatCircle method then use the lineString it returns to draw the line with Mapbox.

```
const start = point(chunk[0].coordinates);
const end = point(chunk[1].coordinates);
const circle = greatCircle(start, end);

prevState.map.addSource(`Route-line-${i}`, {
    type: 'geojson',
    data: circle,
});
```